# Rails - How to refactor application.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

My application.js file is getting messy.

application.js:

```
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#authorinfo').popover();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#publisherinfo').popover();
});
...[and many more similar functions] 
//= require_tree .
```

view:

```
<a class="btn inline" href="#" id="authorinfo" rel="popover" data-content="Section...."><i class="icon-question-sign"></i></a>
```

The bootstrap popover javascript does not seem to work with classes, only id elements and I have also had difficulty moving the javascript out of application.js.

Any ideas on how to refactor?

Comment: You can extract code outside  appplication.js in separate file. If you use ```//=require_tree .``` it will automatically included into page js

Comment: I put the functions in app/assets/javascripts/objectinfo.js and they no longer work.

Comment: @Bob, that seems like a sufficient answer to me (rather than just a comment).

Comment: @JimStewart - posted it as separate answer).

Comment: @Okyekyein - did you see it included into source code of your page?

Comment: yes it does. around the top as "<script src="/assets/objectinfo.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>"

Comment: One more thing you don't need to use `$(document).ready(function(){` multiple times, you can add all those inside logics to single definition. It actually mean the inside code will only run after the document is ready, so no need to define it several times.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract code outside appplication.js in separate file. If you use `//=require_tree .` it will automatically included into page js